# datepickerdialog inside a dialog android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have an activity thats declared as Dialog(using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`) in my application. The activity should be declared as a Dialog and there is no exception for this.

Inside this dialog, i have a button, that triggers, DatePickerDialog and i have followed the [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) to implement it.

My problem is, when i declare the "Dialog Activity" as just Activity, I get the datepickerdialog as intended. Below is the image when its just Activity.

[image]

But, when i declare the Activity as "Dialog Activity"(from manifest), here is what it looks like...

[image]

How can i achieve the Holo style for the datepickerdialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use, `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`to get it to work the way i wanted.